My kafka streams is failing to connect to the upstash schema registry
Curling this https://right-boa-11231-eu1-rest-kafka.upstash.io/schema-registry/schemas/ids/8?fetchMaxId=false&subject=test1-value returns
{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User\",\"namespace\":\"fr.potato\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"favorite_number\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"timestamp_string\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"}


hence it seems like the problem is with my Kstreams app and not the schema registry. I have tried every configuration under the sun, but I am still getting this exception.
2024-07-15 12:50:00 DEBUG StreamThread:1201 - stream-thread [enrichement-app-14-7e65669d-662f-44a6-b47a-30af74085b4e-StreamThread-1] Main Consumer poll completed in 133 ms and fetched 1 records from partitions [test1-0]
2024-07-15 12:50:00 DEBUG RestService:292 - Sending GET with input null to https://right-boa-11231-eu1-rest-kafka.upstash.io/schema-registry/schemas/ids/8?fetchMaxId=false&subject=test1-value
2024-07-15 12:50:00 ERROR LogAndFailExceptionHandler:39 - 
Exception
 caught during Deserialization, taskId: 0_0, topic: test1, partition: 0, offset: 0
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException
: Error retrieving Avro value schema for id 8
  at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.toKafkaException(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:805) ~[kafka-schema-serializer-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:415) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:188) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:107) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:102) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroDeserializer.deserialize(GenericAvroDeserializer.java:63) ~[kafka-streams-avro-serde-5.2.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroDeserializer.deserialize(GenericAvroDeserializer.java:39) ~[kafka-streams-avro-serde-5.2.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:62) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:58) ~[kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66) [kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:204) [kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:128) [kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:285) [kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:1039) [kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:1782) [kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollPhase(StreamThread.java:1208) [kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnceWithoutProcessingThreads(StreamThread.java:909) [kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:686) [kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
  at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:645) [kafka-streams-3.7.1.jar:?]
Caused by: 
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException
: null; error code: 0
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:336) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:409) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:916) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:900) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.getId(RestService.java:880) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaByIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:333) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:464) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-7.6.1.jar:?]
  at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.schemaFromRegistry(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:398) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-7.6.1.jar:?]
  ... 17 more

this is my app
package fr.potato;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndContinueExceptionHandler;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig;
import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.GenericAvroSerde;
import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Enrichement {
  static String auth = "username:pw";
  static String sourceTopicName = "test1";
  static String targetTopicName = "test2";
  static String schemaRegistryUrl = "https://right-boa-11231-eu1-rest-kafka.upstash.io/schema-registry";
  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Enrichement.class);

  // @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "enrichement-app-14");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "https://right-boa-11231-eu1-kafka.upstash.io:9092");
    props.put("sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256");
    props.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
    props.put("sasl.jaas.config",
        "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"username\" password=\"pw\";");
    props.put("basic.auth.credentials.source", "USER_INFO");
    props.put("basic.auth.user.info", auth);
    // https://right-boa-11231-eu1-rest-kafka.upstash.io/schema-registry/schemas/ids/8?fetchMaxId=false&subject=test1-value
    props.put("schema.registry.url", "right-boa-11231-eu1-rest-kafka.upstash.io/schema-registry");
    props.put("debug", "true");
    props.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https");

    props.put("key.converter", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter");
    props.put("value.converter", "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter");
    props.put("value.converter.schema.registry.url", "right-boa-11231-eu1-rest-kafka.upstash.io/schema-registry");

    props.put("key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source", "USER_INFO");
    props.put("key.converter.basic.auth.user.info", auth);
    props.put("value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source", "USER_INFO");
    props.put("value.converter.basic.auth.user.info", auth);

    props.put("auto.register.schemas", false);
    props.put("use.latest.version", true);

    final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap(
        "schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);

    final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
    valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false); // `false` for record values

    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String, GenericRecord> inputStream = builder.stream(sourceTopicName,
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), valueGenericAvroSerde));

    inputStream
        .peek((key, value) -> System.out.println("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value))
        .to(targetTopicName, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), valueGenericAvroSerde));

    try {
      KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
      streams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler((Thread thread, Throwable throwable) -> {
        logger.error("Uncaught exception in thread " + thread, throwable);
      });
      streams.start();
      System.out.println("Kafka Streams app started successfully.");

      Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Error starting Kafka Streams app: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It may be to late however I think you forgot to give a full URL of schema registry
